# Find the mistake.

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

We all know the product rule of differentiation

That, $(uv)'=u'v+v'u$

I tried proving the same and what I have done I'm showing you, **you have to find the mistake in my proof (if you are interested )**

$$
(g(x).h(x))'=f'(x)
$$
$$
={\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]}
$$
$$
={\frac{d}{dx}[g(x).h(x)]}
$$
$$
=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x).h(x+\delta x)-g(x).h(x)}{\delta x}}
$$
$$
=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x).h(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}-\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x).h(x)}{\delta x}}
$$
$$
=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}.\lim_{\delta x\to 0}h(x+\delta x)-\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)}{\delta x}}.\lim_{\delta x\to 0}h(x)
$$
$$
=(\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}).h(x)-(\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)}{\delta x}}).h(x)
$$
$$
=(\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}-\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)}{\delta x}}).h(x)
$$
$$
=(\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x)-g(x)}{\delta x}}).h(x)
$$
$$
=g'(x).h(x)
$$

What I'm getting from my proof is definitely wrong but what I have used in my proof is all correct **so where I'm doing the mistake.**

Please help me!!!

Comment: Dear Singh, please avoid giving orders. It is definitely not our work to do anything on this site.

Comment: First, I'm not sure why $\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{g(x).h(x)/\delta x}$ would exist

Comment: The equality $\lim \limits_{\delta x\to 0}\left({\dfrac{g(x)\cdot h(x)}{\delta x}}\right)=\lim \limits_{\delta x\to 0}\left({\dfrac{g(x)}{\delta x}}\cdot \lim\limits_{\delta x\to 0}h(x)\right)$ is only true if both limits on the RHS exist.

Comment: @NilsMatthes Sorry Sir, it was my mistake. But it was written to make it clear what I'm asking in the question. THERE WAS A REQUEST AT THE END.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake is in the 5th line: You cannot split the limit like this because the limit
$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{g(x) h(x)}{\delta x}$$
doesn't exist, you would have $\frac{f(x)}0$ there.

Instead, try adding and subtracting $g(x+\delta x)h(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is $$\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x).h(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x+\delta x)}{\delta x}}.\lim_{\delta x\to 0}h(x+\delta x)$$
and
$$\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x).h(x)}{\delta x}}=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)}{\delta x}}.\lim_{\delta x\to 0}h(x)$$

you can't seperate them by this way.